# editing a profile field from within a block?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

**hello everyone...** hope i could describe my problem well enough.

i have a field called "cell number" and a check-box called "send notifications" inside user profiles. i want to create a block for editing these fields, in order for the user to be able to have quick access to them without having to go all the way to the profile page, and also to put focus on them and encourage the user to fill them out.

can anyone tell me how to achieve this? i searched SO and goggled for it and couldn't find an answer. WOULD VERY APPRECIATE SOME READING POINTERS

**thanks a lot everyone!**

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to write some php you can use the drupal API to build a custom form. This should get you started: 
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/embed-some-user-profile-fields-in-a-block-form